# How to add the multimedia content fetched from tridion in XML Format?

Tags: content-manager, multimedia, xml

The requirement is to have the multimedia content (i.e., images) added in the XML format. We are trying to fetch the content added in the page level using the Tridion.ContentManager assembly as shown in below snippet and using the XMLWriter to further generate the XML Data.

```
public string GetDescription(IdentifiableObject item)
{
  string strval = string.Empty;
  if (item is Page)
  {
    Page page = item as Page;
    if (page.Metadata != null && page.MetadataSchema != null)
    {
      ItemFields metadataFields = new ItemFields(page.Metadata, page.MetadataSchema);
      foreach (var field in metadataFields)
      {
        if (field.Name.ToLower() == "metafields")
        {
          ItemFields embeddedLink = ((EmbeddedSchemaField)metadataFields["metafields"]).Value;
          strval = ((TextField)embeddedLink["description"]).Value;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return strval;
}

xmlWriter.WriteStartAttribute("description");
xmlWwriter.WriteString(GetDescription(item));
xmlWriter.WriteEndAttribute();
```

However text fields can be implemented as mentioned above but how to deal with the multimedia content like images? Is there any way to fetch the images in the byte[] or any other format from the tridion side to process further? Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to get a page's content for Content Manager templating or some type of integration? You'll need to iterate over the Components or Component Presentations to get the page-level content. You'll find Multimedia Components typically linked from Components added to the page or subsequently "nested" Components linked from page-level Components. Multimedia Components could also be added directly to the page.

Comment: Hi @AlvinReyes, Yeah It is for templating only. Our query is that after fetching the  image from component presentations or from page level, Is there any way we can include them in the XML format? We initially thought of converting it into base64 string format but that would add load to the XML file and is not advisable. Is there any other way we can achieve this? Hope i make sense, Please let me know. Thanks!